# How to ignore step and set exact amount on jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a number of questions regarding jQuery Sliders.

I have the following jsfiddle to help explain.
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindoyleie/jh8yn2v6/)**

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  range: 'min',
  value: 5000,
  min: 5000,
  max: 1000000,
  step: 5000,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#value").html($("#slider").slider("value") + ' years');
    $("#value").css("margin-left", (ui.value - 5000) / (1000000 - 500) * 80 + "%");
    $("#value").css("left", "-50px");
  }
});

$("#value").html($("#slider").slider("value") + ' years');
$("#value").css("margin-left", (5000 - 5000) / (1000000 - 5000) * 80 + "%");
$("#value").css("left", "-50px");

$('#set-value').click(function() {
  $("#slider").slider("value", 171098);
  $("#value").html($("#slider").slider("value") + ' years');
  $("#value").css("margin-left", ($("#slider").slider("value") - 5000) / (1000000 - 5000) * 80 + "%");
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#slider {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#value {
  background: #CC99CC;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="form-group">
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <div id="value"></div>
</div>

<button id="set-value">Set</button>
```

1. I'm seeing is that if you use the slider and move it to either end (`min` or `max`) it appears to display a value which is the `step` value greater than min or less than max. 
   **The question is**: why doesn't the slider allow me to move to the minimum or maximum positions?
2. The question is represented by the `Set` button in the jsfiddle.
   In reality we have some JavaScript which comes up with an amount here for here we're simply setting a fixed value. However the slider snaps to the nearest step point.
    **The question is:** Is there a way to ignore the steps when you have a specific amount?  The range is quite large so the steps are handy for slider use but I'd still like to be able to set the exact amount when I use the set button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just delay your logic inside slide callback   http://jsfiddle.net/jh8yn2v6/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the first question:

Replace `$("#slider").slider("value")` with `ui.value`.

About the second question:

You can do kind of "patch". When you click on the button, set the `step` property to `1`. When the user start dragging the slider, turn it to `5000` again.

You can see the both of the answers in the snippet below.

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  range: 'min',
  value: 5000,
  min: 5000,
  max: 1000000,
  step: 5000,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#value").html(ui.value + ' years');
    $("#value").css("margin-left", (ui.value - 5000) / (1000000 - 500) * 80 + "%");
    $("#value").css("left", "-50px");
  },
  start: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).slider( "option", "step", 5000);
  }
});

$("#value").html($("#slider").slider("value") + ' years');
$("#value").css("margin-left", (5000 - 5000) / (1000000 - 5000) * 80 + "%");
$("#value").css("left", "-50px");

$('#set-value').click(function() {
  $("#slider").slider( "option", "step", 1).slider("value", 171098);
  $("#value").html($("#slider").slider("value") + ' years');
  $("#value").css("margin-left", ($("#slider").slider("value") - 5000) / (1000000 - 5000) * 80 + "%");
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#slider {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#value {
  background: #CC99CC;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="form-group">
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <div id="value"></div>
</div>

<button id="set-value">Set</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ui.value in the event handlers is the crux of getting the proper inputs.

```
...
slide: function(event, ui) {
    $value.text(ui.value + ' years');
....
```

Check out this fiddle that also shows how to can better position your moving value element.

[Slider with value centered under slider handle](https://jsfiddle.net/hecswn96/)